# Neodymium magnets as nanoparticles bonded with atmospheric amide to create a magnetic 'air curtain'?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, hard-science, biochemistry

Amide bonds are extremely stable and their half-life for hydrolysis in neutral aqueous solution is estimated to be seven years. Amides bind to metal ions through the carbonyl oxygen.

Neodymium Magnets

Are a type of rare-earth magnet comprised of an alloy of neodymium, iron and boron. They were devised in 1982 by General Motors and Sumitomo Special Metals. Neodymium magnets are the strongest type of permanent magnet commercially available. They are used when strong permanent magnets are required, particularly in cordless tool motors, hard disk drives and magnetic fasteners.

Neodymium magnet nanoparticles sprayed into the air, bonds with atmospheric amides to form neodymium magnetic 'air curtain'.

Several factors such as long-term stability, health risk and the practicality of the immobilization of the nanoparticles in the air will also have to be considered.

Is this neodymium magnetic 'air curtain' feasible?

Comment: What keeps the particles from simply precipitating out as dust -- onto every ferromagnetic object in range?

Comment: And with each other...?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here, specifically?

Comment: One iron atom (or neodymium or whatever) is not ferromagnetic. Molecules or organometallic complexes containing iron (or neodymium or whatever) are not  ferromagnetic. (There may be exceptional exceptions, but I don't know of such.) Iron (or neodymium or whatever) is ferromagnetic only in its bulk metallic form. Practical experiment: find an old rusty fence, and scrape some rust on a piece of paper. Rust is extremely soft, so it will be easy to collect. Take a permanent magnet and see if the rust flakes are attracted to the magnet.

Comment: @ZeissIkon '...practicality of the immobilization of the nanoparticles in the air will also have to be considered' I have no idea, hence the question.

Comment: Actually, naturally occurring magnetite is an oxide of iron (and so is non-magnetic hematite -- one is Fe2O3, the other Fe3O4, but I forget which is which).  Magnetic tape and disk coatings are usually made from hydrated magnetite (top quality tape used to be chromium oxide).

Comment: @Cadence, I meant to write air shield and the thought about having an air field. Either way, mobilization of the nanoparticles in the air will be impossible. The air shield/field is essentially to keep electromagnetic signals in, and prevent foreign signals from entering. It was meant as a defense mechanism for a particular region in my novel, but I see the idea is a bit too abstract, even for fiction.

Comment: @ChagatNahn If you want to block magnetic signals, you would be better using a dome around or city, working more or less like a faraday cage. That is more scientifically sound than this air spray thing.

Comment: what exactly *is* an air field?  Magnetic fields extend into the air already.  The earth's magnetic field for example is not contained within the earth, it extends outward through the atmosphere.  Do you maybe mean an "air curtain"  like the flowing air in open entrance to a large building that is used to retain the heated air inside?

Comment: @Nate White, yes, something of that sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Even if the nano particles could retain their magnetic properties, what you would have done is released a bunch of particles that are free to orient themselves and connect with other particles.  They would quickly collect into a mass and fall,  raining out of the air.  The further they had to fall, the larger they would become.

Answer (score 5):

No, nanoparticles will not retain the magnetic properties of the bulk material, as they will lose their constructive force without being physically locked to the same polarity with regards to each other.